# How did Vyasa become immortal?

Tags: vyasa

Vyasa is one of the 7 chiranjeevis or immortals. He is considered to be the author of Mahabharata. How did he become immortal?

Comment: please answer my question in answer section, not in comment section

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the boon from Deva-Adi-Deva Mahadeva.

> "'Parasara said,—**"In former times I gratified Sarva, O king. I then cherished the desire of obtaining a son** that would be possessed of great ascetic merit, endued with superior energy, and addressed to high Yoga, that would earn world-wide fame, arrange the Vedas, and become the home of prosperity, that would be devoted to the Vedas and the Brahmanas and be distinguished for compassion. **Even such a son was desired by me from Maheswara.** Knowing that this was the wish of my heart, that foremost of Deities said unto me,—'Through the fruition of that object of thine which thou wishest to obtain from me, **thou shalt have a son of the name of Krishna.** In that creation which shall be known after the name of Savarni-Manu, that son of thine shall be reckoned among the seven Rishis. **He shall arrange the Vedas,** and be the propagator of Kuru's race. He shall, besides, be the author of the ancient histories and do good to the universe. Endued with severe penances, **he shall, again, be the dear friend of Sakra. Freed from diseases of every kind, that son of thine, O Parasara, shall besides, be immortal.'**—Having said these words, the great Deity disappeared there and then. Even such is the good, O Yudhishthira, that I have obtained from that indestructible and immutable God, endued with the highest penances and supreme energy." (MBH. 13-49-45).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Wonderful reference!!!

Comment: Thank You. ..